# What dialect is this?

Tags: dialects

This is a shot from a manga called 飴色{あめいろ}パラドックス by 夏目{なつめ}イサク. I was wondering what dialect the police-man was speaking in?

[image]

I know he's in 田舎{いなか}/東北{とうほく} as that's all the mangaka specifies, but I was wondering if it was a specific dialect. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very pure and specific dialect is rarely used in manga.  Why not?  Because the vast majority of readers would not understand it then.  (The Tokyo dialect might be the only exception.)

The cop's speech looks Touhoku-ish for sure, but if you looked closely, except for the use of 「わらす」 (= わらし), almost all of the dialectal elements used are the voicing of the consonants that are pronounced unvoiced in "standard" Japanese.  I am referring to:

「さいぎん」,「あだり」,「しでた」,「おだぐ」, etc.

I have lived in Nagoya and Tokyo all of my life.  If I can understand the cop's lines if I just mentally got rid of all the **゛**'s (the dots), then I know that that is not a full-on dialect.

Comment: この「わらす」は子供という意味ではないでしょうか。子供のことを「わらし／わらす」と言う方言が、東北に幾つかありますので。余談ですが、身近にいるネイティブ津軽弁スピーカーに聞いたら、例えばここで言う「おだぐすか？＝あなたですか？」は、津軽弁では「なだが？」などと言うそうです。もしも台詞がリアル東北方言で書かれていたら、方言と見る前に「何語！？」ってなりそうですね。

Comment: HiruneDiverさんが書かれているように、わらすは童【わらし】ですね。座敷わらしのわらし。

Comment: あと、純粋な方言語彙でないのは、必ずしも非方言話者のために作者がたなごころを加えたとは限らず、実際の話者が公的な場面で標準語をしゃべってるつもり、または標準語をかなり意識した変種を使ってる可能性もあります。この場合警察官ですし。